# Is there way to identify Class and object

Tags: python, django

For example I have class

```
Class Cls:
   var 1 
   var 2

   def func(self):
      --- do some statement
```

Now, I can simply import class and create object

```
import Cls
clsObj = Cls()
```

Here, Cls is class and clsObj is instance of class. Is there any way that I distinguish between them.

Thank you

Comment: You can't really `import` classes - are you sure this is the real code?

Comment: @Krishna - Please accept answers to your old, answered questions by clicking the check mark next to the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use the builtin type() which gives the type of a particular object. type(clsObj) will give Instance as the answer. You can also check with `isinstance`
`isinstance(clsObj,Cls)` will return `True` whereas `isinstance(Cls,Cls)` will return `False`

Comment: Only old-style class instances are of type instance. The type of a new style class instance is it's class.

Comment: I can pass one parameter only e.g. Cls or clsObj. So based on coming parameter, I have to identify. e.g. 

    doSomething(clsObj):
        if clsObj is class: do something object
        else: do something class

Comment: You can use the hasattr(Obj,'__class__') to check if it is object of the class. Note it depends that you have `__init__` call in your class and create an object.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* this takes all cases into account:

```
def isclass(obj):
    try:
        class_ = obj.__class__
    except AttributeError:
        # It's an old-style class
        return True
    try:
        class_.__class__
    except AttributeError:
        # It's an old-style instance
        return False
    # It's new-style
    return isinstance(obj, type)
```

Now let's test it to make sure it works as intended/expected:

```
def test():
    class OldStyle: pass

    class NewStyle(object): pass

    def class_factory():
        return type("DynamicClass", (object,), {})

    class MetaClass(type):
        def __new__(mcls, *args):
            if args:
                return type(*args)
            return class_factory()

    class WithMeta(object):
        __metaclass__ = MetaClass
        def __call__(self):
            return self

    confusing = WithMeta()

    for name, obj in locals().items():
        templ = "{0:>26s} == {1!r:>5}, {2:>26s} == {3!r:>5}"
        print templ.format(
            "isclass({0})".format(name), isclass(obj),
            "isclass({0}())".format(name), isclass(obj()))
```

Output:

```
         isclass(OldStyle) ==  True,        isclass(OldStyle()) == False
         isclass(NewStyle) ==  True,        isclass(NewStyle()) == False
         isclass(WithMeta) ==  True,        isclass(WithMeta()) == False
        isclass(MetaClass) ==  True,       isclass(MetaClass()) ==  True
    isclass(class_factory) == False,   isclass(class_factory()) ==  True
        isclass(confusing) == False,       isclass(confusing()) == False
```

`MetaClass`, `class_factory` and `confusing` illustrate that what constitutes a class in python is debatable, and shows how the `isclass` function handles these cases.

**Re: agf**

*`MetaClass` isn't meant to be instantiated like that, so your tricks to avoid an error really just confuse the issue; printing "Error" for `MetaClass()` would be more correct.*

Did you or I write `MetaClass`? I meant it to be instantiated like that. I'll grant you it makes little sense to have a metaclass (or a class factory function) that creates "the same" class each time it's invoked, and of course it's confusing. However, for these specific purposes I wanted to illustrate that a metaclass creates a class when instantiated, and having lots of arguments to `MetaClass()` would be a combo-breaker in the output. :) So in principle I agree with you, but for this specific purpose I do it this way, and python allows me to do so.

*`__call__` happens BEFORE `__new__` so what `WithMeta()`, `confusing`, and `confusing()` show is correct.*

If you by "happens" means "is parsed, compiled and bound" then yes, that happens first. I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at here. I agree it's correct -- of course it's correct, this code was written and run, and I posted the results I got, so it can't help but be correct. I don't see what `__call__` has to do with it. Could you elaborate?

*You never actually instantiate `WithMeta`. You should just remove that `__call__` and show Error for `confusing()`*

I'm quite sure I *do* instantiate `WithMeta`:

```
>>> WithMeta()
<isclass.WithMeta object at 0xb784574c>
```

When I write `WithMeta()`, python will check if `type(WithMeta).__new__` is defined, and it is, so python then supplies the class name, bases and namespace dict as arguments to `MetaClass.__new__()`. It returns the `WithMeta` class object, which is made by calling `type` with the same arguments.

On the other hand, `confusing()` is the same as `type(confusing).__dict__["__call__"](confusing)`, which just returns the argument, so that `confusing == confusing()`.

Comment: Use `isinstance` not `issubclass`. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: There could be a problem if the class is a subclass of `type`, so its instances are actually classes... as in a metaclass. Anyway this can't be solved without an explicit registry of what is to be considered a 'class' rather than an 'instance'.

Comment: @agf `isinstance(obj, cls)` and `issubclass(type(obj), cls)` are the same. So the answer is correct, and you have to change the argument if you want to use isinstance.

Comment: I know it works, and I know you'd need to change the argument. It's one less call and it's really what you want to check there -- whether or not the object is an instance of `type`.

Comment: @saverio Since OP didn't define it, I've interpreted him to mean that a class is anything that may be instantiated.

Comment: I think you're being a bit too tricky here. `MetaClass` isn't meant to be instantiated like that, so your tricks to avoid an error really just confuse the issue; printing "Error" for `MetaClass()` would be more correct. `__call__` happens BEFORE `__new__` so what `WithMeta()`, `confusing`, and `confusing()` show is correct -- you never actually instantiate WithMeta. You should just remove that `__call__` and show `Error` for `confusing()`.

Comment: Let me explain myself better. if your goal was to explicate when you get an instance, when you get a class, when you get a type, your update was a step backwards, as what `MetaClass` does in your example is __not__ what a normal metaclass does, and what `WithMeta` does is __not__ what a normal class with it's `__metaclass__` attribute set does. I didn't mean your code was _wrong_, just that it didn't really clarify the core ideas I thought you were trying to convey. I was suggesting a way that it would more clearly show how metaclasses and their instances act.

Comment: @agf My goal was just to show there are things that might "act" like a class that may be instantiated, but where `isclass(`"class"`)` and `isclass(`"instance"`)` do not correspond to expectations: `True` and `False`. I still don't understand what you're getting at though. What exactly does a _normal_ metaclass do? And in what way does `WithMeta` not act like a _normal_ class with `__metaclass__` set?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd need to, but you can do this:

```
if type(obj) == type:
    # It's a class.
else:
    # It's an instance of a class.
```

Comment: This is only true for new-style classes without metaclasses -- he's created an old-style class above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `__class__` - `clsObj.__class__`

From [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html):

> Each value is an object, and therefore has a class (also called its
>   type). It is stored as `object.__class__`.

Comment: for both Class or Class object, it returns class name. My job ti identify given input is class or object isntance

Comment: So I didn't understand your question, sorry!

Comment: But you should remember that every class is an object too!

Comment: @Krishna - No, it doesn't. A  new style class without a metaclass will have `<type 'type'>` in it's `__class__` field, and an old style class will have no class field. An instance of a class will have it's class in the `__class__` field